# questions about tomcat access vps from external wifi and machine

Tags: java, tomcat, port, vps, ubuntu-20.04

First at all thanks for your time.

I would like to solve some doubts that I have in relation to a vps under Ubuntu22.04.

I already installed everything related to TOMCAT.

my duads are:

once the java API is served in tomcat, could I access it from any notebook and wifi network? I would not be achieving that

If in my external browser I write ip:8080 should I be able to access the tomcat of my vps?

I looked everywhere but I still can't figure out how to access my vps tomcat from external.

What configurations do you recommend my external computer is under the ubuntu operating system?

I already tried to disable the ubuntu firewall.

add address="0.0.0.0"

I made changes to catalina e files